# Basic plotting in running IDL procedure

Tags: plot, idl-programming-language

I started learning IDL a few hours ago. I have constructed the following procedure in a .pro called 'plots.pro':

```
PRO PLOTS
num=findgen(40)*10
line=sin(num*!DtoR)
plot, num, line
END
```

It seems I should get a plot of the line as a function of num. However, I instead get the following error message:

'plots
     ^
% PLOTS: Incorrect number of arguments.'

I wonder if you may point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure name "PLOTS" is already used by a different IDL procedure. You can rename your procedure (and file name) so that it doesn't conflict with PLOTS.

```
PRO my_plot
  num=findgen(40)*10
  line=sin(num*!DtoR)
  plot, num, line
END

IDL> my_plot
```